# Select product information via mysql

Tags: mysql, products

I need to select all the **attributes of the products these columns** of all products in the tables:

Any suggestion?

--

TABLE: catalog_product_entity

COLUMN: **sku**

--

TABLE: catalog_product_index_price

COLUMN: **price**

--

TABLE: cataloginventory_stock_status

COLUMN: **qty**

COLUMN: **stock_status**

--

TABLE: catalog_product_index_price

COLUMN: **price**

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Now, i have this: SELECT entity_id as product_id, sku, qty as quantidade, stock_status as estoque FROM catalog_product_entity 
INNER JOIN cataloginventory_stock_status ON (cataloginventory_stock_status.product_id = entity_id)

Answer (score 1):

Ready, I got it.

Just use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT catalog_product_entity.entity_id, sku, price as preco, qty as quantidade, stock_status as estoque FROM catalog_product_entity INNER JOIN cataloginventory_stock_status ON (cataloginventory_stock_status.product_id = entity_id) INNER JOIN catalog_product_index_price ON (catalog_product_index_price.entity_id = catalog_product_entity.entity_id)
```

Comment: Cool! Three things to mention here: 
1) you could use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` if you want to catch situations where a product doesn't have stock or price
2) the query works for single store Magento installations; if you have more than one store you might want to add `AND catalog_product_index_price.website_id=$websiteId` to the second join
3) you might be interested in `catalog_product_index_price.final_price` field also since that's the actual selling price.

Comment: Btw, it's perfectly fine to mark your own answer as the accepted answer, so please feel free to do so if it solves the original question :)